# Getting count of elements sent to html in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

So in my views.py, I use the render function which sends a dictionary of a bunch of values to my html page as so.

```
results = { 
                'cssjsslinks' : cssjsslinks,
                'encodingused' : charencoding,
                'metaused' : metatagsused,
                'leftouttags' : leftouttags,
                'errorwords' : errwords,
                'whatsupdoc' : doc_type,
                'alttrue' : alttrue,
                'altfalse' : altfalse,
                'emptyhref' : emptyhref,
                'url' : url,
    }

    #Finally, render the page and send results
    return render(request, 'analyzer/resultsfinal.html', results)
```

In my html page, I'm trying to display a table with the number of columns as the number of items in my results dictionary. But something like

```
{% for i in results %}
     <td>..</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Doesn't work. My last resort would be to send the length of the dictionary itself as an item in the dictionary and then loop through that. I can loop through the items of the dictionary. Just not the dictionary itself. Is there some length function I can use for the dictionary here?

I've definitely missed something fundamental. Help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The number of keys in the dict can be obtained in the template via `{{ results|len }}`. But: Why does the `for`-loop *not work*, i.e. what is the intended output? Please add an example of that.. Currently you are only looping over the *keys* of the dictionary.

Comment: Not sure why the for loop doesn't work. I'm not even trying to print any item in the dictionary. I put some dummy html paragraphs into the for loop and if it enters the loop, it's supposed to print the html paragraphs. But it doesn't even enter the loop. Have a look at Daniel's reply. He might be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, you're not sending the dictionary `results` to the template at all: you're sending its contents. You could nest it, if you really wanted:

```
return render(request, 'analyzer/resultsfinal.html', {'results': results})
```

but that would mean you would have to refer to every variable via the containing dict:

```
{{ results.cssjsslinks }}
```

which is likely to be annoying.

So, no, there's no way of easily doing this without including the count yourself.

Comment: Side note: While passing the raw dictionary usually works, passing at least a `RequestContext` is advisable, otherwise any template context processors are not applied.

Comment: @dhke Not true. The `render` shortcut takes care of that.

Comment: Yeah, from what I read from the official documentation, I agree with Daniel.
And thanks Daniel!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misread the code path. It ends in up in `template.loader.render_to_string()` with both `context `and `context_instance` defined, which triggers the *legacy* code path. I cannot think of a quick and decent way to clean this up, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have django installed on my current machine so this is at the top of my head.

First of send `results`as a dictionary to your template as suggested by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) and not just the content

```
return render(request, 'analyzer/resultsfinal.html', {'results': results})
```

Now in the template you can access `{{results}}` to get all the key : values to build your columns

```
{% for key, value in results %}
   <td> {{ key }}: {{value}} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

If for some reason you still need the number of items in the dictionary, you can use the `length` filter

```
{{ results|length }}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the only way of achieving it other than sending the dictionary size as a part of the dict itself. Problem with this is, well not exactly a problem but I'll have to keep referencing each variable with the key:value notation. Will implement one of the methods I guess. Just thought there was a cleaner way of doing it and I was missing it. Thanks!